# Where is my audio device?

Tags: sound, microphone, headphones, input, output

I'm new to Ubuntu, and haven't been able to figure this out. When I got to my sound settings, I can select an output device. My PC has two different aux plugs for headphones and a microphone. Neither appear when looking for an input/output device. Help?
I'm using an MSI Stealth GS75